# Keeping Checkboxes Checked

Tags: css, checkbox

I'm very new at programming, and my first project was putting my fantasy football list online for friends. www.davebloomquist.com/thelist

The problem is, I haven't learned how to keep the checkboxes checked when people jump between pages.

Can someone help (and talk to me like an idiot- i.e. not only tell me the code, but where to place it?)

Thank you so much.

Comment: set a cookie using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it in your browsers localstorage. The answer can be found from here [Remember checkbox with localstorage onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679967/remember-checkbox-with-localstorage-onclick)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function saveToStorage(){
    var items = [];
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var len = checkboxes.length;
    for(var i=0;i < len;i++){
        el = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[i];
        if(el.checked == true){
            items.push({value:true});
        }else{
            items.push({value:false});
        }
    }
    var json_string = JSON.stringify(items);
    localStorage.setItem("checkbox_values", json_string);
}
function retrieveFromStorage(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var len = checkboxes.length;
    var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkbox_values"));
    for(var i=0;i < len;i++){
        el = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[i];
        el.checked = items[i].value;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="retrieveFromStorage()">
    <table class= "table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>PLAYER</th>
          <th>RD</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">1</span></td>
        <td>Aaron Rodgers</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">2</span></td>
        <td>Drew Brees</td>
        <td>1-2</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">3</span></td>
        <td>Peyton Manning</td>
        <td>2-3</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">4</span></td>
        <td>Tom Brady</td>
        <td>2-3</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">5</span></td>
        <td>Matt Ryan</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">6</span></td>
        <td>Cam Newton</td>
        <td>3-4</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">7</span></td>
        <td>Matt Stafford</td>
        <td>4-5</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">8</span></td>
        <td>Tony Romo</td>
        <td>4-5</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">9</span></td>
        <td>Andrew Luck</td>
        <td>4-5</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">10</span></td>
        <td>Russell Wilson</td>
        <td>5-6</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">11</span></td>
        <td>Colin Kaepernick</td>
        <td>5-6</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">12</span></td>
        <td>Robert Griffin III</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">13</span></td>
        <td>Jay Cutler</td>
        <td>8-9</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">14</span></td>
        <td>Eli Manning</td>
        <td>8-9</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">15</span></td>
        <td>Ben Roethlisberger</td>
        <td>8-9</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">16</span></td>
        <td>Joe Flacco</td>
        <td>8-9</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">17</span></td>
        <td>Mike Vick</td>
        <td>9-10</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">18</span></td>
        <td>Andy Dalton</td>
        <td>9-10</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">19</span></td>
        <td>Matt Schaub</td>
        <td>9-10</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">20</span></td>
        <td>Phillip Rivers</td>
        <td>11-12</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">21</span></td>
        <td>Alex Smith</td>
        <td>12+</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">22</span></td>
        <td>Carson Palmer</td>
        <td>12+</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">23</span></td>
        <td>Brandon Weeden</td>
        <td>12+</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">24</span></td>
        <td>Josh Freeman</td>
        <td>12+</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="saveToStorage()">25</span></td>
        <td>Sam Bradford</td>
        <td>12+</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Get all checkbox then store them in an object.
2. Parse the object into string then save it to localstorage.
3. Get the saved string from local storage. Parse it as object again.
4. Loop the object and apply each values to checkbox

Comment: Hi Roseann. Thanks for answering. You can see what I added a script to the head of my code (http://www.davebloomquist.com/thelist/wr.html), but still no luck. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You have to be able save each checkbox values to the localstorage by specifying an id

Answer (score 0):

Once you change pages anything entered into the input fields (checkboxes) will be lost unless your setting those selections in the DB, Session, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think the checkboxes don't stay checked when you jump around to different pages because of exactly what you are doing, "jumping around to different pages".

If the different pages are static, with no ViewState or session to keep the state of the checkboxes, they will revert to whatever they are coded to be when the page loads.